# I will offer up a few bits of advice (???)

Tags: phrases

I think that this means simply "I'll give you a few of advice."
My question is how "offer up" and "offer" are different. 
In the dictionary, "offer up" is to worship or present as an act of worship, which I don't think is this case.

### Also "a few bits of advice" is commonly used? Or is this because the author who wrote this is a programmer?

Note: As an ESL person, most cases, meaning of what native speakers say presumably can be understood like this question. But the nuance of them is not clear especially in the case that speakers want to express their secondary intention indirectly. This sentence came from a programming book. Usually, coding book does not use such expression as "offer up". Also, there are many Jargons used by only computer science people. So, I wondered the possibility of the other meanings than dictionary meanings. Also, suddenly I thought that "a bits of advice" might be a tweak too for fun because the author used exaggeration in the "offer up".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Offer" and "offer up" have different functions in English. We might call them "postures" because they are more about the attitude of the speaker.

To "offer" something is simply to make it available to someone else, either to give (as in a material object) or to share (as in things that can't be given away completely, like knowledge: my telling you a fact doesn't remove the fact from my mind).

To "offer up" a thing encompasses the meaning of "offer" but adds a twist. It suggests that the person doing the offering does so out of reverence, or piety, or from generosity, or as a personal sacrifice.

Or it may be that the speaker simply wants to sound more grandiloquent.

That the "bits" in "bits of advice" has anything to do with programming is merely coincidental. People were offering bits of advice long before there were computers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Robusto gave a good answer on the offer/offer up part.

RE "a few bits of advice": You could simply say, "I will offer advice". (Not "I will offer of advice", just "I will offer advice". Without the "bits", there's nothing for the advice to be "of".) By saying "a few bits of advice", the speaker indicates that he does not have a lot of advice, just a few small pieces. This is a common phrase; it might be considered an idiom. The idea is, I can't give you a complete explanation, but here are a few things that I know.

As Robusto says, it has nothing to do with bits in programming. The word "bit" here simply means "a small piece or amount". Like you can say, "I ate a little bit of cake" or "He cut off a bit of the paper."